# File with mixed keys-values to Dictionary

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary, graph

Hello I have a file with this format:

```
1 5
2 6
3 6
4 5
5 6
5 7
5 8
...
```

and what I want is to make a dictionary like this:

```
1:5
2:6
3:6
4:5
5: 1, 4, 6, 7, 8
6: 2, 3, 5,
....
```

The file is the connections between nodes of an undirected graph and I would like to convert it to a dictionary with the node as the key and the neighbors of this node as values (adjacency list).

My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the data from the file to match the node with all his neighbors.

I tried this,

```
nodeList = list()
with open(file) as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile.readlines():
        nodeList.append(tuple(line.strip().split()))

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in nodeList:
    d[k].append(v)
```

and the result is a dictionary:
`[...('5', ['6', '7', '8']),..., ('1', ['5']),.., ('4', ['5']).....]`
but it's not exactly correct, because for example I want `4` and `1` to appear as the value in key `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in nodeList:
    d[k].append(v)
    d[v].append(k)
```

gives me the result I want.
Thx for helping me.